# Is passing URL param to element's src vulnerable?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, javascript-injection

Is passing URL parameter to src path security issue? For example:

```
var type = getUrlParameter('type');
element.scr = "js/" + type + "/main.js"
```

Thank you

Comment: No.  It isn't a security issue.  Why on earth would you do it though?  What you do with it could cause security concerns.

Comment: I would treat it as an issue, and do validation on the type parameter against a list of allowed types. It is not an issue by itself, but could be one in combination with another issue.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers, it is not possible to execute javascript from the src attribut of img ([source OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Script_in_IMG_tags)). I tested it with `<script src="...">` too and i could not inject any javascript over URL parameters.

But this only goes for modern browsers (and only for this specific case where you get the URL parameter using javascript). You should definitely always escape the output just to be sure.

So to answer your question, yes, it still is a security issue because not all people use modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

If element doesn't get required *url parameter* as `src` due to page-loading issues, script not loading or even script failing etc, it's gonna be a hard time for you to debug since the user will be redirected to a `url` that is not desired...